# Getting authenticated user from DLL called by web app

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've created a web app that calls a DLL. The web app is set to impersonate and has windows auth. Inside the DLL when I check:

```
System.Environment.UserName;
```

it has my AD username. All works great there. I have a 3rd party web app that allows us to create our own DLL plugins. I set this up the same way, windows auth, and impersonate, but inside a DLL that website loads when I check the Environment.UserName it just shows the pools identity name.

I also noticed that inside this 3rd party web app DLL System.Web.HttpContext.Curernt.User is null (just the User part).

My question is how can I debug this to see what's happening behind the scenes? Is there some process watcher or browser debug tools where I can see what's up? I have access to the IIS the 3rd party web site sites on and in fact it's the same as my little test app that works.

The only difference, I guess, is that the 3rd party site is on the Default Web Site and is a sub website to that. My test website is on it's own website (hope I explained that right). Basically in IIS my test site has it's own globe icon with bin/content/etc under it, while this site sites under Default Web Site.

I'm wondering if there are any further debugging steps I can do on the 3rd party website. Is there any way I can trace every step in this website request? What is the steps for impersonation and how can I tell what step may be failing?

Comment: Just a note : System.Environment.UserName gives user name of the person who is currently logged on.

Comment: The executing thread limits whether you can get the log on user info. So either you force the library to only work if `HttpContext.Current.User` is not null, or give up such an idea completely.